# Fixing spacing in a PRN file programmatically using PHP

Tags: php, regex

My task is to look through PRN files and find the line in the file that the signature graphic should be placed on (a line of underscores).  It only appears on the last page of the file. If the signature line is on line 16 or above, it should be moved down to line 17 and everything below that (the name and date) gets moved down also. That's all fine. The problem is that the PRN file is a template and the line of underscores should be x amount of spaces from the line number. I say x because the template could change - which leads to my problem.

What I did initially was to find the signature line, check what the line number was, move it down if needed and then put the rest of the line back together using the pieces from the regex with the new line number. But sometimes the line of underscores appears on the line between the lines that have line numbers. I can't use the part of the regex that finds the spaces, because it will just repeat the wrong number of spaces on the new line.

Is there a way to fix the spacing without hard coding it and not have it break if someone changes the template?

Here is the function:

```
public function changeSignatureLine($prn) {
    // Find the signature line
    preg_match('/(\s{12})(\d{2})(\s+)(\_{10,})/', $prn, $matches);
    $linePosition = strpos($prn, $matches[0]);
    // pull out the line number
    $lineNumber = $matches[2]; 
    // set the spacing
    $spacing = '                              '; 
    // signature line is spacing plus underscores
    $signatureLine = $spacing . $matches[4]; 
    $nameMatch = array();
    // get text from beginning of signature line to end of file
    $endOfPage = substr($prn, $linePosition); 
    // pull out name from line under signature line
    preg_match('/\s{12}' . ($lineNumber + 1) . '\s+(\w*\s\w*\.?\s?\w*)/', $endOfPage, $nameMatch); 
    // name is space plus text of name
    $name = $spacing . $nameMatch[1]; 
    // pull out date from two lines below signature line
    preg_match('/\s{12}' . ($lineNumber + 2) . '\s+(\w*\s\d{1,2}\,\s\d{4})/', $endOfPage, $dateMatch); 
    // date is space plus text of date
    $date = $spacing . $dateMatch[1]; 
    // Everything from beginning of file to position of signature line
    $newText = substr($prn, 0, $linePosition); 
    // if signature line is on line 17 or higher, reformat each line with the correct spacing
    if ($lineNumber > 16) { 
        $newText .= $matches[1] . $lineNumber . $signatureLine . "\n\n";
        $newText .= $matches[1] . ($lineNumber + 1) . $name . "\n\n";
        $newText .= $matches[1] . ($lineNumber + 2) . $date . "\n\n";
    } else { // if signature line is on line 16 or lower, add in blank lines and move signature line to 17, name line to 18 and date line to 19
        if ($lineNumber == 15) {
            $newText .= '            15' . "\n\n";
        }
        $newText .= $matches[1] . '16' . "\n\n";
        $newText .= $matches[1] . '17' . $signatureLine . "\n\n";
        $newText .= $matches[1] . '18' . $name . "\n\n";
        $newText .= $matches[1] . '19' . $date . "\n\n";
    }
    // finish writing the rest of the page
    for ($i = ($lineNumber + 2); $i <= 25; $i++) { 
        $newText .= $matches[1] . $i . "\n\n";
    }
    return $newText;
}
```

Comment: Example `$prn` data would be needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the spacing is getting messed up is because there is a small graphic in each file that the user must remove before creating the PRN. If they don't remove it, the spacing gets messed up. The "answer" from my boss was that these people should be told to remove the graphic (as they're supposed to) and it is not a programming problem.